# Django admin doesn't show Users and Groups

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm confused because I've created a project, created some models, forms etc. and checked `localhost/admin`. But I can't see nothing there. Not **Users** nor **Groups**. I've tried to register **User** but it's returning that **User** is already registered.

What to do? Did I forgot something in `settings.py`?

[image]

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
"""
Django settings for dolava_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@%*ev9w$*r*-4_3tfpgvp5nvod127=5k_knnp&fccrijo6%o4('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dolava_app',
    'django_extensions'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dolava_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dolava_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**EDIT:**
URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from dolava_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html') ),
    url(r'^accounts/registration/$',views.registration)
]
```

Comment: Are you logged in with a superuser? Can you post your `dolava_project.urls` also?

Comment: Yes, I'm superuser. I've created new one to be sure. Adding urls at the bottom of the question.

Comment: The settings.py file was generated by Django 1.8.7 but is the running version the same? What does `python manage.py version` say?

Comment: It's 1.9.7. So there is a problem. Is it possible to repair it to works with 1.9.7 or should I restart the whole project?

Comment: This should work with Django 1.9.7, but this gives an interesting information. If the running version was lower than 1.7, it could have been a missing `autodiscover()`, but here it's not the case.

Comment: You should probably check [Django 1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/).

Comment: admin urls should now be imported as `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` but the other syntax is only deprecated, this should not be the issue. Does `python manage.py check` report any issue? Have you overriden some django admin templates, or the `AdminSite` class (or `admin.site` object)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to also add your main app name in your setting app
2- create model in your models.py
3- create admin.py file add your table name in that
4- Make migrations & and migrate so it will create tables
5- create super user
6- After that login on admin